# WebView não captura gestos

Tags: ios, swift

WKWebView carrega o link porém não consigo realizar ação alguma no site

ViewController

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class promoVC: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.loadURL(strURL: "https://rh.mazza.tech/web/guest/webuser");
}

}
 extension promoVC : WKNavigationDelegate{

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Webview is loading")
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("")
}
}
```

Comment: Seu código compila? WKWebView não possui um método chamado loadURL(String). O método é load(URLRequest) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414954-load

Comment: Compila, ele abre o site, porém não consigo usar o site

Answer (score 0):

O metodo da webView **loadURL** não compilala, voce precisar utilizar o método **load**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = URL(string: "https://rh.mazza.tech/web/guest/webuser") {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }
}
}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     print("Webview is loading")
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("")
}
}
```